# Confused over following async behavior

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out following code and am not sure what the std::async part is doing:

```
std::vector<double> RunParallel( std::vector<std::vector<int>> args)  
{
    std::vector<std::future<double>> results(args.size());
    for( int iter_job = 0;  iter_job < args.size(); ++iter_job )
    {
        int arg1 = args[iter_job][0];
        int arg2 = args[iter_job][1];
        results[iter_job]= std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
              { return (foo(arg1,arg2)); });
    }
    std::vector<double> returnValues;
    for(int iter_job =0; iter_job<args.size(); ++iter_job)
    {
          returnValues.push_back(results[iter_job].get());
    }
 }
```

I don't understand what the return is doing in the std::async call.

Somehow this code is leading to strange results and I wonder if it has to do with the return call in the middle of the first for loop.

Comment: You might want to add the foo() function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[&]{ return (foo(arg1,arg2)); }` is a *lambda expression* that produces a *closure* taking no arguments and returning `foo(arg1, arg2)` upon invocation.

`arg1` and `arg2` are captured by reference in the closure. This means that as soon as an iteration of the `for` loop ends, the closure will hold **dangling references**. This is likely the cause of your problem.

Capture `arg1` and `arg2` by value instead:

```
[arg1, arg2]{ return foo(arg1, arg2); }
```

Using the default `&` or `=` captures is usually a bad idea as they can introduce subtle bugs. Prefer listing your captures explicitly unless you have a good reason to not do so.

Comment: Does using the [=] eliminate the dangling references ?

Comment: @steviekm3: it captures everything by value, so yes. Please don't ignore my advice about `&` and `=`.

Comment: You could also just call `std::async(std::launch::async, foo, arg1, arg2)` and avoid the capturing lambda

Comment: Yes I will change code to list out the captures.  I’m not sure why in this case code is using capturing lambda instead just doing function call.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `return` in the for loop - the `return` is in the function that you're passing to `async`.

The problem is that the function is capturing `arg1` and `arg2` by reference, and when it's called some time in the future those objects no longer exist, so attempting to access them is undefined.

Replace the capture list `[&]` with `[arg1, arg2]` to capture them by value instead.
(And throw in an empty parameter list for good measure: `[arg1, arg2]() { ... }`.)

Comment: This sounds correct as the strange results are duplicated values in the return vector, when not running in parallel produced unique values.